# Cannot find a way to use both at same time, bottom sheet and bottom navigation bar in android compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-layout

In android compose, there is `Scaffold` composable function to create a layout that contains bottom navigation bar and there is another function named `BottomSheetScaffold` to create a layout that contains bottom navigation bar.

 My question is how to achieve both the bottom sheet and Bottom Navigation bar in same layout?

I treid using BottomSheetScaffold and adding the bottom navigation bar in the layout but I failed when I used NavHost besides it in the same column.
Simplified code for the case:

```kotlin
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        { BottomSheetComposable },

        topBar = {
            TopAppBar()
        },
        sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp
    ) {
        Column() {
            NavHost(
                navController,
                startDestination = "route"
            ) {
                Composable("route") {}
            }
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(60.dp)
            ) {
                BottomNavigationBar()
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A temporary solution would to use `scaffold` inside `BottomSheetScaffold` content

```kotlin
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        sheetShape = BottomSheetShape,
        sheetContent = {
            currentBottomSheetScreen?.let {
                MainBottomSheetLayout(
                    it, navController, textToSpeech,
                    closeSheet
                )
            }


        }) {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = { LinguisticTopAppBar(navController, mainViewModel, openSheet) },
            bottomBar = {
                BottomNavigationBar(mainViewModel, navController)
            },

            ) {

            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(it)) {
                MainContent(
                    navController,
                    mainViewModel,
                    openSheet
                )
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: is it possible to apply for this  (https://stackoverflow.com/q/71077550/10991969) question?